# RewriteRule for encoded url (%2F)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a very silly seeming problem but i haven't found an answer to it. 
I have an upload server and an UploadServlet. 
Previously the routing `{server}/upload/(filename.txt)` worked like a charm, now we are encoding the path which encodes `/` charecter as `%2F` so if the file path was = `/xcv` now becomes = `%2Fxcv` and this doesn't get re-routed to the servlet i want. Is there any simple flag setting or something i'm missing here to avoid this, or will i have to use an entire new Rewrite rule, if so, why isn't this simple rule working ?

```
RewriteRule ^/fileupload?$ [F]
RewriteRule ^/fileupload(.*)$ /(server)/$1 [PT, L]
```

Comment: Does adding `NE` flag (`[NE,PT,L]`) help?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently %2F seems to be valid only when used within a query string. You can fix the problem by replacing all instances of %2F with %252F.